# Android device beginning to go out of control when I reboot it

Tags: malware

Sometime back I had connected my Android mobile HTC Explorer to a compromised system. It has been about one year since then.

Sometimes my phone tends to react in strange ways. Sometimes(once or twice), calls were made. I tried scanning with my antivirus but no avail. I even factory reset the phone many times, but now a strange thing is happening to my phone.

As soon as I reboot my phone, when it is connected to the power supply, it begins to go out of control. It seems like some buttons are pressed inside and new apps and windows open. New browser windows etc open and sometimes calls are made,and games installed. I have to manually cancel the calls. But it is only on bootup.

I did not notice it some other time. What do you think is wrong in my phone? If malware is present, why does antivirus fail to detect it? I am really worried because I use the phone for transactions. Or is it some hardware problem? What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Its a very common thing i have seen with **HTC** (might be valid for others but i have only used HTC) 
You should change your "Charger" and the "Data Cable" used along that charger ... the Data cable does this auto opening of apps and touching of buttons .. try borrowing someones charger and putting it in you will notice it gets fine..